# how may i add integer list to route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, binding, asp.net-mvc-routing, url.action

I'm trying to add int[] array to my Url.Action something like this:

```
var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary();

for (int i = 0; i < Model.GroupsId.Length; i++) {
    routeData.Add("GroupsId[" + i + "]", Model.GroupsId[i]);
}
```

in my view:

```
Url.Action("Index", routeData)
```

but in html I'm getting:

```
GroupsId%5B0%5D=1213&GroupsId%5B0%5D=1214
```

and not:

```
GroupsId=1213&GroupsId=1214
```

I need it because I have a checkbox list, and when I do post I'm binding groupIds to int[] and then pass to view where I have export button with Url.Action that doesn't work correctly for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot generate such url using the standard helpers because of the duplicate query string parameter names. It's unfortunate but it is how things are.

Here's what you can instead in order to generate such url:

```
var baseUrl = Url.Action("Index", "SomeController", null, Request.Url.Scheme);
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(baseUrl);
uriBuilder.Query = string.Join("&", Model.GroupsId.Select(x => "groupsid=" + x));
string url = uriBuilder.ToString();
```