# How do I pass int array to RouteValueDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need generate this url: `http://localhost:3178/Reports/?GroupId=1211&GroupId=1237`

I'm trying:

```
var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary();
routeData.Add("GroupId", "1, 2");
```

getting: `GroupId=1,%202`

or

```
routeData.Add("GroupId", "1");
routeData.Add("GroupId", "2");
```

getting: An item with the same key has already been added

and even

```
routeData.Add("GroupId[0]", "1");
routeData.Add("GroupId[1]", "2");
```

getting: `?GroupId%5B0%5D=1&GroupId%5B1%5D=2`

it's possible to somehow fix my issue?

Comment: And something like that won't be good ? http://localhost:3178/Reports/?GroupId=1211,1237. I'm not sure that you can do what you want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how may i add integer list to route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395290/how-may-i-add-integer-list-to-route)

Comment: @Thomas Jaskula, no cuz default binder will not know how to bind it :(

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, it's my own question :-| . i still have no answer to it

Comment: @msony, the fact that you have no answer to your question is not a reason to post duplicates. It's even worse: it means it is intentional because you know of the existence of the exact same question.

Comment: @msony, I have posted an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 1):

The RouteValueDictionary is meant to provide information to routes.  As such, I don't think it has the capability you're asking for.  I've been using a custom helper to populate query string data based on what I pass into it:

```
    public static string BuildPath(RequestContext context, string routeName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, object additionalParams)
    {
        var vpd = RouteTable.Routes[routeName].GetVirtualPath(context, routeValues);

        if (vpd == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var virtualpath = vpd.VirtualPath;
        var addparams = BuildAdditionalParams(additionalParams);

        if (!virtualpath.Contains("?") && addparams.Length > 0)
            virtualpath = virtualpath + "?" + addparams;
        else if (virtualpath.Contains("?") && addparams.Length > 0)
            virtualpath = virtualpath + "&" + addparams;

        return "/" + virtualpath;
    }

    protected static string BuildAdditionalParams(object additionalParams)
    {
        if (additionalParams == null)
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Type type = additionalParams.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();

        Action<string, string> addProperty = (name, value) =>
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append("&");
            sb.Append(name);
            sb.Append("=");
            sb.Append(value);
        };

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            var simplevalue = prop.GetValue(additionalParams, null);
            if (simplevalue != null)
            {
                Type propertyType = prop.PropertyType;
                if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType) != null)
                {
                    propertyType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
                }

                if (propertyType.IsEnum) 
                {
                    addProperty(prop.Name, ((int)simplevalue).ToString());
                }
                else if (propertyType.IsArray && propertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                    foreach (var val in prop.GetValue(additionalParams, null) as IEnumerable)                        
                        addProperty(prop.Name, val.ToString());                                                    
                }                    
                else
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(simplevalue.ToString()))
                        addProperty(prop.Name, simplevalue.ToString());                        
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This function will build a full path to your route and append the values in the additionalParams object as query string data.  This can handle arrays, enums, nullable values, and other types that by executing their ToString method.

Hope this helps!